# Unexpected result when using "exists", "extractvalue" and "is not null"

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Why

```
SELECT 1  FROM dual where extractvalue(xmltype('<A>1</A>'),'A') IS not NULL
```

return 1

but

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM dual
WHERE  EXISTS
  (
  SELECT 1  FROM dual where extractvalue(xmltype('<A>1</A>'),'A') IS not NULL
  );
```

return 0 ?

Edit : By replacing extractvalue with extract, i get 1...

Comment: Your second query returns 1 to me.

Comment: Here is my version (select * from v$version) and I've got 0 :  
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extractvalue` is deprecated

you can try this :

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (select '<A>1</A>' as data from dual),xmltable('A' passing xmltype(data) columns result varchar2(1028) path '.')
WHERE 
result is not null;
```